# Samba Network Path not found

Tags: linux, windows, network-shares, samba

I am trying to set up a Samba-Connection between my linux server and my home computer. However, when I try to add the Samba share as a network drive using

```
net use k: \\ip.ip.ip.ip\shared password /user:username
```

I get the following error message:

```
System Error 53 has occured.
The network path was not found.
```

I just set the Samba server up using

```
sudo smbpasswd -a username
sudo net usershare add shared /home/user/shared "Shared Files" username:f
```

That is all I did with the configs, everything else is freshly installed.

```
sudo smbclient -L ip.ip.ip.ip
```

Does in fact print out the shares I am looking for when executed in the linux shell.

Any ideas on how to resolve the problem?

Edit: My Windows Firewall and my AVG Firewall are both disabled. I'm running Windows 8.1

Edit: testparm -s

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[homes]"
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
[global]
        server string = %h server
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S
        create mask = 0700
        directory mask = 0700
        browseable = No

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        create mask = 0700
        printable = Yes
        print ok = Yes
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers
```

Edit: sudo net usershare info

```
[shared]
path=/home/username/shared
comment=Shared Files
usershare_acl=V220110897556081\username:F,
guest_ok=n
```

Comment: that particular message should indicate that the IP is bad, or the service cannot be found, or there is an error in its expression. can you ping the IP? check testparm -s on the server, to check for config issues. confirm that the ~\shared directory allows at least read priv for the user you are using. on the server, make sure samba is started, and run `netstat -ntlup` and confirm 139 and 445 are listening.

Comment: I actually resolved the IP out of the `ping domain.com` command. The testparm -s output has been added to the post. I'm giving ~/shared the permissions of `755` temporarily. Samba is up and running and listening on 139 and 445.

Comment: what does `sudo net usershare shared` show? from https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/net.8.html the permission letter should be capital, so you may want to use the usershare add command again with a capital F. Personally I kind of hate usershares, since their config is so limited, but I'm turning into an old fart....

Comment: Deleted and re-added the share with a capital F, doesn't seem to make a difference sadly. Added the information outputted by `sudo net usershare info` to the post. If you have any suggestions on how to solve this without using usershares, I'll be happy to try and test them out.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with my Samba server. I fixed it by forcing the Samba server's NetBIOS name to resolve to its local IP in the hosts file. To be clear, I made this modification to the hosts file on the Windows machine I use to access the Samba share.

That is, open `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` as Administrator and add a line with the samba host IP and hostname like so:

`192.168.0.2  RASPBERRYPI`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
Articles like http://woshub.com/smb-1-0-support-in-windows-server-2012-r2/ and
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/detect-enable-disable-smbv1-smbv2-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows-server were great.

However, none of them mentioned to tweak the following group policies (Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/Security Options):

- “Network security: LAN Manager authentication level” change to Send LM & NTLM responses
- “Network security: Minimum session security for NTLM SSP based (including secure RPC) servers “ - Disable Require 128-bit encryption option
- “Network security: Minimum session security for NTLM SSP based (including secure RPC) clients “ - Disable Require 128-bit encryption option

... which finally fixed the problem.
Btw, using Windows 2012R2 to connect to a very old samba.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on debian 10.

Solution:

```bash
sudo apt install samba-vfs-modules
```

P.S. My problem was because of module widelinks.so